# Many-to-many relationships in Laravel Model Factory

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, factory, multi-tenant, saas

I am building a SaaS using [Tenancy for Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) and I am having issues creating model factories to seed the database. This is a 2-part question.

I have the following data structure for tenants:

- `User` model

  - `accounts(): $this->belongsToMany(Account::class);`
- `Account` model

  - `users(): $this->belongsToMany(User::class);`
  - `venues(): $this->hasMany(Venue::class);`
- `Venue` model

  - `account(): $this->belongsTo(Account::class);` (using an `account_id` column on the `venues` table)

I also have an `account_user` pivot table to store the relationship between the `User` and `Account` models with `account_id` and `user_id` columns.

**Part one of my question:**

I have created factories for the models and I would now like to seed the database.

This is my code:

`TenantSeeder.php`

`User::factory()->count(10)->hasAccounts(10)->create();`

However when I run it, I get the following error:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'account_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into account_user (account_id, user_id) values (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2), (?, 2))`

I tried to specify the tables at the belongsToMany Relationships of the User and Account model, however I still get this error.

I have also tried to add the relationship with the `->has()` method of the Factory instead of the magic method, but I get the same results.

`User::factory()->count(10)->has(Account::factory()->count(10))->create();`

**The second part of my question:**

Is there a way to seed the Venues at the same time as the users and accounts?

Ie. something like this:

```
 User::factory()
            ->count(10)
            ->has(
                Account::factory()
                    ->count(10)
                    ->has(
                        Venue::factory()
                            ->count(10)
                    )
            )
            ->create();
```

In my VenueFactory class I am adding the `account_id` column's value like this:

```
return [
            'account_id' => Account::factory(),
            .....
]
```

This, however, throws the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'account_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `venues` (`account_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 2023-02-14 12:35:40, 2023-02-14 12:35:40))
```

According to the documentation, however, this should work?

Any idea what could cause these two issues? Is it related to Tenancy?